# From prime to prime by squaring the digits

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I took prime $131$, squared digits of it and wrote them in natural order as they appear, from left to right, and obtained $191$, then I obtained $1811$ by the same procedure, and then $16411$ and then $1361611$, and $131,191,1811,16411$ are primes and $1361611$ is not.

To illustrate how to arrive at the next number in sequence from previous one, take, for example, $16411$.

We have: $1^2=1$ and $6^2=36$ and $4^2=16$ and $1^2=1$ and $1^2=1$ so we obtain $1361611$ from $16411$.

> Can we generate in this way as large a number of different (to avoid loops like one that starts with $11$) primes as we want? Or there is some law/laws that do not allow that?

Comment: Also asked today on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561484/from-prime-to-prime-by-squaring-the-digits

Comment: Although the first chain of length $5$ starts already at $2111$, there are no such chains of length more than $5$ for primes <10000000

Comment: The first one of length $6$ starts at $12815137$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That is also obtained by Peter on MSE question linked above., He also found no chains of length seven.

Comment: This could serve as a question in recreational mathematics, but this forum is not the best for your question.  Consider analyzing the (repeated) productions for each digit, and count the number of ones produced.  My guess is that any number will lead to a fixed point (namely a binary looking number) or will encounter a multiple of 3.  Gerhard "Others Aren't Ready To Play" Paseman, 2017.12.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman My intuition also suggests me that, but I do not know how to turn it into a proof. And although it looks recreational, and somehow it is, I do not see why I shouldn´t ask it here? But thanks. I added "recreational" tag.

Comment: Some questions of this sort are admitted by the community.  However, a poor analogy is like talking vegan recipes in a barbecue forum. A few of the regular forum members might appreciate it, but most won't. The professional mathematicians here that maintain this forum like to have this forum reflect their goals and interests.  There are other forums than this which would receive your question more warmly.  Gerhard "Is Starting To Get Hungry" Paseman, 2017.12.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I just had a generous portion of pork stew with capers; in such cases I am usually more inclined to pursue questions like this as my predatory impulses get calmed down for a while

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Look at the numbers of occurences of each non-zero  digit modulo $3$. You have a $9\times 9$ transition matrix $A$. The first question to ask is if for every $x\in\mathbb Z_3^9\setminus\{\pm(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\}$ you can find $k$ such that $y^TA^k x=0$ in $\mathbb Z_3$ where $y=(1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0)$. If so, the story is over (you are guaranteed to hit a multiple of $3$ except when you have all $1$'s in the beginning). If not, it gets interesting. So write a program and tell us the result.

Comment: If this statement is true, it will be well beyond current technology to prove.  For instance, since none of the squares of single digit numbers contains 7, this claim would imply that there are infinitely many primes that do not have 7 in their digit expansion.  This has only been proven very recently by Maynard https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01041 , and is highly non-trivial.   This problem is significantly harder than that.

Comment: On the other hand, the claim is likely true.  If $a_1,\dots,a_k$ is any string of numbers obtained by this procedure, then $10^n a_i + b, i=1,\dots,k$ is also obtainable by this procedure whenever $b$ is an $n$ digit number consisting entirely of $0$s and $1$s.  One can restrict to those $b$ that are equal to $1$ mod $k!$ (there are about $\asymp 2^n/k!$ of these when $n$ is large) to avoid local obstructions, and probabilistic heuristics then suggest that one can make all of the $10^n a_i + b$ prime for some $n,b$.

Comment: p.s. Actually, the claim would imply that there are infinitely many primes whose digit expansion has no 7s and only a bounded number of 0s, 2s, and 5s.  This is already beyond the reach of Maynard's method at present (though potentially a refinement of his approach would eventually be able to establish this).

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you Terry because of your reaction to this question. I am just an amateur and had no idea that this problem of mine would have connection to results of Maynard, which is surely nice to know. This problem can further be generalized in a variety of ways but since already this is put on hold as off-topic, it is better that I do not do that here.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Nevermind the "on hold" status. What was the program output?

Comment: @fedja Did not write it. I do not have any programming language on my computer. I only sometimes use Wolfram Alpha on the web.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen OK, I'll do it myself then, but later. Note that C++, Python, Pascal and a few other languages can be installed for free any time and take less disk space all together than some fancy application allowing you to organize the pictures you took with your cell phone in a neat way (not to mention the space taken by the pictures themselves).

Comment: @fedja Thanks for the information, also, tell me about the results you obtained when you obtain them, nice to have you here because of the support and advices.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Fortunately or unfortunately, there are $34$ non-trivial starting combinations that never hit a multiple of $3$. The simplest one is $12377$. So Gerhard was overly {opt/pess}imistic.

Comment: Assuming we can prove this sequence grows exponentially (I think that's true because every digit greater than $3$ becomes two digits), if it contains an infinite number of primes for some starting point then my [finding primes infinitely-often](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289269/seeking-references-for-finding-primes-infinitely-often) problem is in polynomial time.

Comment: Can this question be migrated to Math StackExchange?